# Use cout/cin when overloading IO Operators in C++?

Tags: c++, io, operators, overloading

I am testing some C++ code related to overloading IO operators. The code as follows:

```
class Student {
 private:
     int no;
 public:
     Student(int n)
     {
         this->no = n;
     }
     int getNo() const {
         return this->no;
     }
     friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Student& s);
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& s);
 };
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& s){
     cout << s.getNo(); // use cout instead of os
     return os;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Student& s) 
{
    cin >> s.no; // use cin instead of is
    return is;
}
```

However, inside the `<<` and `>>`, I can use:

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& s){
     os << s.getNo(); // use os instead of cout
     return os;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Student& s) 
{
    is >> s.no; // use is instead of cin
    return is;
}
```

In `<<`, I use os object instead of cout and the similarity for `>>` operator. So, I am curious to know if there is any difference of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is obvious, is/os are input/output streams while cin/cout are the standard input/output streams. cin/cout are instances of i/o streams, not synonyms.

The point being, there are streams other than standard input/output, such as files, string streams, and whatever custom implementation you can think of. If you use cin/cout in your streaming operators, ignoring the stream they should read/write to, then you'll end up with

```
file_stream << some_student;
```

printing to the standard output, rather than to the file where its supposed to.

Comment: What do you mean by standard input/output streams? are they the ones that "are preconnected input and output channels between a computer program and its environment (typically a text terminal) when it begins execution" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)??